# Double-click a JTree node and get its name

Tags: java, actionlistener, jtree

How do I double-click a JTree node and get its name?

If I call `evt.getSource()` it seems that the object returned is a JTree. I can't cast it to a DefaultMutableTreeNode.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html)

> If you are interested in detecting either double-click events or when
>   a user clicks on a node, regardless of whether or not it was selected,
>   we recommend you do the following:

```
final JTree tree = ...;

MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int selRow = tree.getRowForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        TreePath selPath = tree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if(selRow != -1) {
            if(e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                mySingleClick(selRow, selPath);
            }
            else if(e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                myDoubleClick(selRow, selPath);
            }
        }
    }
};
tree.addMouseListener(ml);
```

To get the nodes from the `TreePath` you can walk the path or simply, in your case, use [`TreePath#getLastPathComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html#getLastPathComponent%28%29).

This returns an `Object`, so you will need to cast back to the required node type yourself.

Comment: Yes.I know this.But how do I use the selRow and selPath??

Comment: Well the next thing you need to do is read the API entry for [`TreePath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html)

Answer (score 11):

The following code works for me.

```
tree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)
                       tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
                if (node == null) return;
                Object nodeInfo = node.getUserObject();
                // Cast nodeInfo to your object and do whatever you want
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

MadProgrammer has pretty much everything covered.  To get the object you can call

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode =
   ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)selPath.getLastPathComponent()).
   getUserObject();
```

Comment: Maybe we should use it as Object and then cast:  
  
`Object selectedNode =  ( (DefaultMutableTreeNode) selPath.getLastPathComponent()).getUserObject();`

Answer (score 1):

My example. We can detect Double-click with delay.

```
public class TreeListener extends MouseAdapter{
    private JTree _Tree;
    private boolean singleClick  = true;
    private int doubleClickDelay = 300;
    private Timer timer;    

    public TreeListener(JTree tree)
    {
        this._Tree = tree;
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                timer.stop();
                if (singleClick) {
                    singleClickHandler(e);
                } else {
                    try {
                        doubleClickHandler(e);
                    } catch (ParseException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }; 
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(doubleClickDelay, actionListener);
        timer.setRepeats(false);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { 
        if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
            singleClick = true;
            timer.start();
        } else {
            singleClick = false;
        }
    }

     private void singleClickHandler(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("-- single click --");
    }

     private void doubleClickHandler(ActionEvent e) throws ParseException {         
        System.out.println("-- double click -- id=");      

    }     
}
```