# double click and transfer files using library ftp4j

Tags: java, swing, ftp

How can I do double click on `JTree` of my laptop to transfer files to server using FTP4j
thank you

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    String s = arbre.getLastSelectedPathComponent().toString();
    File file = new File(s);
    if(file.isFile()) {
        System.out.println("c'est un fichier");
        if(e.getClickCount()==2){
      client.upload(file);
      }
}
```

Comment: Which part are you having issues with?  Double clicking a `JTree` node or transferring the files with ftp4j?

Comment: part of using double click to transfer files: detect double click if it is file and transfer using upload the problem is how to do it I am not able to code it

Answer (score 2):

Using `getClickCount()`, you can detect double clicks in a `MouseListener`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12848028/230513). Start the transfer in your implementation of the `doInBackground()` method of [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Use `setProgress()` to notify a listening progress indicator as the transfer proceeds, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513). You can show progress in a `TreeCellRenderer`, illustrated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html). Beacuase nodes share the same renderer, you'll need to store progress elsewhere
, typically in your implementation of `TreeModel`.

Addendum: A very simple way to display a `JTree` of files is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837208/230513).

Comment: Can You please give me an example of source code ?  I don't understand You, I am just beginner in programming 
best regards

Comment: Something like [this](http://techdive.in/java/ftp4j-file-transfer-protocol-tutorial)?

Comment: Can you please give me a program I'm just beginner

Comment: Essen unfortunely there is no an easy way. You have to learn by your own, not "do the job for me". Take a look to [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)