# Java JTree node is a clickable URL link

Tags: java, jtree

I'm trying to make a node be a clickable URL, but I just can't seem to figure out how.

I've searched high and low, and I can't seem to find a solution.

This is my code:

```
public class NyttigeLinks {

    private static JFrame nyttigeLinks;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                    initialize();
            }

    public NyttigeLinks() {

    }

    private static void initialize() {
        nyttigeLinks = new JFrame();
        nyttigeLinks.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 350, 650));
        nyttigeLinks.getContentPane().setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 350, 650));
        nyttigeLinks.getContentPane().setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        nyttigeLinks.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel("");
        logoLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(NyttigeLinks.class.getResource("/images/ssiLogo.jpg")));
        logoLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 350, 60);

        JTree tree = new JTree();

        nyttigeLinks.getContentPane().add(logoLabel);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 71, 324, 508);
        nyttigeLinks.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        tree.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(
            new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Nyttige Links\t") {
                {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node_1;
                    node_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Projekt Wiki");
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("AO"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Attends"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Carlsberg"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("COOP"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Dafgaard"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Jysk DK"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Jysk SE"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Kvadrat"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Solar"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Stockmann"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Tine"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Unicef"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Vectura"));
                    add(node_1);
                    node_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Helpdesk Norcic");
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Test"));
                    add(node_1);
                    node_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Test");
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("AO"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Attends"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Carlsberg"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("COOP"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Dafgaard"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Jysk DK"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Jysk SE"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Kvadrat"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Solar"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Stockmann"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Tine"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Unicef"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("VecturaAO"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Attends"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Carlsberg"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("COOP"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Dafgaard"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Jysk DK"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Jysk SE"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Kvadrat"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Solar"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Stockmann"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Tine"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Unicef"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("VecturaAO"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Attends"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Carlsberg"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("COOP"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Dafgaard"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Jysk DK"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Jysk SE"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Kvadrat"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Solar"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Stockmann"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Tine"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Unicef"));
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Vectura"));
                    add(node_1);
                }
            }
        ));
        tree.setBounds(10, 71, 324, 540);
        tree.setRootVisible(false);

        JLabel bottomLabelTop = new JLabel("                   Nyttige Links Version 1.0");
        bottomLabelTop.setBounds(0, 590, 230, 14);
        nyttigeLinks.getContentPane().add(bottomLabelTop);

        JLabel bottomLabelBot = new JLabel("                              Made by xxx");
        bottomLabelBot.setBounds(0, 605, 230, 15);
        nyttigeLinks.getContentPane().add(bottomLabelBot);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Admin");
        btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(NyttigeLinks.class.getResource("/images/appIcon.ico")));
        btnNewButton.setBounds(240, 590, 80, 20);
        nyttigeLinks.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
        nyttigeLinks.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 650));
        nyttigeLinks.setSize(new Dimension(350, 650));
        nyttigeLinks.setResizable(false);
        nyttigeLinks.setTitle("Nyttige Links");
        nyttigeLinks.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(NyttigeLinks.class.getResource("/images/appIcon.ico")));
        nyttigeLinks.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        nyttigeLinks.setBounds(100, 100, 350, 650);
        nyttigeLinks.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        nyttigeLinks.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I apologize for being a bit of a noob, but you gotta start somewhere, right?

If someone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it a lot! Have a good night everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to make the node itself a URL. However, you could accomplish the same thing by using listeners to open the browser when the node is clicked. To open the browser, you can use the [Desktop#browse(URI)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29) method.

On the topic of clicking, I would recommend not opening a URL when a node is single-clicked. For a user that would be very annoying (IMO). Instead, I'd recommend using a double-click. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12848028/3300205) provides a good way to distinguish between a single and double-click, and how to add it to the `Tree`.

---

> [...] but you gotta start somewhere, right?

Exactly! Allow me to give a bit more detail here that will hopefully be helpful for learning a bit more.

One challenge you will face is how to know which URL to open for a given node. Currently you only know the `String` that is displayed, and I think it's a safe assumption that you don't want to be displaying a full URL for each node. Instead of creating the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` objects with a `String` parameter, I would recommend creating an object to pass in to the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` constructor instead. This object can also have a `URI` attribute so it knows which URL to open.

For example:

```
public class LeafNodeObject {
    private final URI uri;

    public LeafNodeObject(final String display, final URI uri) {
        this.display = display;
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    /**
     * Override so that we control what is display on the Node
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return display;
    }

    public void onDoubleClick() {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Nodes can be added like so:

```
node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new LeafNodeObject("Test", new URI("www.eclipse.org"))));
```

And in our listener (slightly modified from the link above):

```
final MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
        final int selRow = tree.getRowForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        final TreePath selPath = tree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (selRow != -1) {
            final DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) selPath.getLastPathComponent();
            if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                // Single click
            } else if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                // Double click
                ((LeafNodeObject) node.getUserObject()).onDoubleClick();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now when there is a double-click event, we call the `onDoubleClick()` method on the `LeafNodeObject` that we've created.

This looks great, except that we will run into class casting issues with nodes that are not leaf nodes! To fix this, we can make a similar class for those nodes (eg. `ParentNodeObject`). In the interest of good OOP, we should recognize the common behavior of these two classes (`onDoubleClick()`, and also an `onSingleClick()`), and create an interface for the shared ability.

For example:

```
public interface NodeObject {
    public void onSingleClick();
    public void onDoubleClick();
}
```

Now we can have our two classes implement this interface:

```
public class ParentNodeObject implements NodeObject {
    private final String display;

    public ParentNodeObject(final String display) {
        this.display = display;
    }

    /**
     * Override so that we control what is display on the Node
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return display;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSingleClick() {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onDoubleClick() {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

public class LeafNodeObject implements NodeObject {
    private final URI uri;

    public LeafNodeObject(final String display, final URI uri) {
        this.display = display;
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    /**
     * Override so that we control what is display on the Node
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return display;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSingleClick() {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onDoubleClick() {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

As a result, in our listener we no longer need to know (and no longer care) whether the node is a parent or leaf node. We can simply call either `onSingleClick()` or `onDoubleClick()`, and the implementation handles the rest!

```
if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
    // Single click
    ((NodeObject) node.getUserObject()).onSingleClick();
} else if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
    // Double click
    ((NodeObject) node.getUserObject()).onDoubleClick();
}
```

Back in your code, the parent and child nodes can be added like so:

```
node_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new ParentNodeObject("Helpdesk Norcic"));
node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new LeafNodeObject("Test", new URI("www.eclipse.org"))));
```

Now, when you single or double-click any node, either the `onSingleClick()` or `onDoubleClick()` methods will also be called. In this case we only care about what happens when there is a double-click on the leaf nodes, so we only need to fill in that method.

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks a lot for your help. I'll look into it tomorrow morning when I'm off work. I don't have anymore time tonight. Thanks a lot, I'll be sure to update this thread with how it goes.

Comment: @TheGreyNight You're welcome! Let me know if there's anything that doesn't make complete sense or could use a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't checked the above mentioned code, here is  how I got around the issue while I was waiting for a reply to this thread:

```
class SelectionListener implements TreeSelectionListener {

    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent se) {
        JTree tree = (JTree) se.getSource();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
        String selectedNodeName = selectedNode.toString();
        if (selectedNode.isLeaf()) {
            if (selectedNodeName == "Unicef") {
                try {
                    java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create("http://www.eb.dk"));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // make a error pop up appear here
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong, please report this to the developer!", "Something went wrong", 0);
                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }
            }

            if (selectedNodeName == "Vectura") {
                try {
                    java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create("http://www.google.com"));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // make a error pop up appear here
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong, please report this to the developer!", "Something went wrong", 0);
                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

It's definitely not a nice way of doing it, since it will lead to A LOT of if statements, but it was simple enough for me to understand by myself.